# How to use read function to read from terminal input (stdin)?

Tags: c, linux

The main function will be in an infinite loop reading the numbers that the user puts in the terminal and storing them on a buffer. My problem is that I need to read from terminal using this function:

`read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`

How can the file descriptor point to the terminal?! (I hope I'm not saying some barbarity)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I already took your advice, but something is missing. This is a small program that I wrote to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int buffer[5], i=0, j;

int main(){
   for(j=0; j<5; j++) buffer[j] = 0;
   while(i<5){
     read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 8);
     printf("->%d\n", buffer[i]);
     i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Outup:

```
1
->2609
2
->0
3
->0
4
->0
5
->0
```

Why this doesn't print the numbers that I inserted?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY If I have a file descriptor STDIN_FILENO, why should I use that function?

Comment: it might be rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On POSIX you can use symbols like `STDIN_FILENO` to represents the input of your application. But beware that the standard input is not always the terminal, especially when you redirect input/output via the shell.

Comment: I didn't understand this part: "when you redirect input/output via the shell".

Comment: If you launch your app with something like "myapp < somefile", then the shell will redirect the input (`STDIN_FILENO` at POSIX level or `stdin`at C level) to the file, and you won't be able to read to the terminal withou reopening it.

Answer (score 2):

Your process has three file descriptors open since it has been spawned: `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO`, `STDERR_FILENO` (0, 1, 2 respectively).
These macros are defined in `unistd.h`.
`read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, bytes)`

Answer (score 2):

By default the program's standard input is on file descriptor 0.

If you really mean to read from the terminal, instead of standard input, you can `open()` `/dev/tty`.

Answer (score 1):

`stdin` is fd `0`,

`stdout` is fd `1`, and

`stderr` is fd `2`.